# JavaFX - ReadOnlyProperty is not read only

Tags: java, javafx, properties

I was looking through the Property API and noticed that ReadOnly properties are actually a subclass of Properties. I thought that was fine at first, since once an object is a `ReadOnlyProperty` it cannot regain the methods inside of `Property`. However that's not true, you can typecast easily to completely get around the read-only portion.

```
public static void change(ReadOnlyIntegerProperty y)
{
    if (y instanceof IntegerProperty)
    {
        IntegerProperty z = (IntegerProperty)y;
        z.set(10);
    }
}
```

Is this intended by design? I get that ReadOnlyProperties are more of a guide for the programmer. But actually doesn't this mean that in the JavaFX api, some properties are provided as ReadOnly, and then can be changed? For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html

`public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Scene> sceneProperty`

I could simply cast that to `ObjectProperty<Scene>` and now I can potentially cause undefined behavior within the library.

I'm trying to implement `Property` in another language that does not support them. What would be a good way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: "ReadOnly properties are actually a subclass of Properties". This isn't true; it's the other way around. [`Property`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html) is a subinterface of `ReadOnlyProperty`. It's possible for an API to return an instance of a (fully writable) `Property` from a method that has return type `ReadOnlyProperty`, but as pointed out in other comments and answers, you shouldn't do that - use a `ReadOnlyWrapper` instead, or return an implementation of `ReadOnlyProperty` that doesn't implement `WritableValue`.

Comment: "I could simply cast that to `ObjectProperty<Scene>`". Did you try this? At least in Java 9.0.4 and later, I get "java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.base@9.0.4/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl cannot be cast to javafx.base@9.0.4/javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper`, which has a writable and a read-only part. The writeable part is what you can use internally as if it is a normal property, the read-only part is what you return to callers:

```
public class Test {
   private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper foo = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper();

   public Test() {
        foo.set(42);
   }

   public final javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerProperty fooProperty() {
       return this.foo.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }   


   public final int getFoo() {
      return this.fooProperty().get();
  }
}
```

Comment: The `ReadOnlyIntegerProperty` returned by `getReadOnlyProperty` is not actually an instance of `IntegerProperty` (or `WritableValue`) anyway, so attempting to do what the OP describes ("callers can still use introspection as you suggest") would simply result in a class cast exception.

Comment: @James_D I see. Good to know. Thx!

Comment: Gotcha. I figured there had to be a trick like that. Unfortunate that the read only property and the writeable property cannot both point to the same object, but that would open it up to the attack I described above. Anyways, thanks!